# Rational Rhapsody Java API licensing

Tags: rhapsody

I wonder if anybody may help me in an open licensing question regarding the IBM Rational Rhapsody Java API. Is there any special license required for the API usage in productive environments? I can't find anything about this topic in the official documents.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

no, there is no special license required for API usage

Regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to open Rhapsody all plugins will work
There is NOT special licensing from IBM to allow plugins to work.

The plugin itself might have a license, that has NOTHING to do with IBM